# Is there a tool that lets you navigate to frequently used directories more easily?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, cd-command

Instead of using cd, pushd, popd, and cdable_vars, and CDPATH, I heard a while ago that there was a tool that "learned" the paths you most frequently navigated to and make shortcuts for those dynamically. Does anyone know what tool I vaguely have in mind?

Comment: Probably this one [Dynamic Shortcut Creation with Bash](http://arun.chagantys.org/blog/?p=293)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short-cut for switching to a given directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226417/short-cut-for-switching-to-a-given-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link from the LinuxJournal with script that would do just this:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10585

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your profile...

```
alias ycd+='pwd>>$HOME/.ycd_list;sort -u -o $HOME/.ycd_list $HOME/.ycd_list'
alias ycd='select ID in $(<$HOME/.ycd_list);do [ $ID ] && cd $ID;break;done'
```

Use `ycd+` to bookmark a directory and use `ycd` to navigate betwwen bookmarked directories.

Original post http://www.unix.com/302288249-post4.html