# How can I cd to a directory without writing its name?

Tags: command-line, files, cd-command

Sometimes it’s annoying to access a directory with the folder name. Say I have a directory named `a b c d`. Apart from using <kbd>Tab</kbd>, is there any way to access the folder without typing the name of the directory?

I know that Linux has a unique identifier every particular file. Can I use this to access the folder? I don’t know whether this can be actually done or how to do it.

I that think when Linux implements a filesystem, it compares two directory names’ uniqueness. So each directory must be unique in a space. But I think that it’s like a primary key in a database system. Is the primary key the *name* of the directory or is there some other unique identifier (perhaps some numbers stored “under the hood”)?

Try to think of this like a process. If you execute the command `ps` on a terminal, it outputs a process list with the name and number of each process. You have to call that process with the process number. Similarly, is there a number for a directory so that you could call the directory with its number instead of calling it with its name?

---

On further investigation, I have found that each directory has a unique `inode`. However, I have not so far found any built-in command to access a directory by its `inode`.

Comment: wildcards work too. otherwise install `zsh` instead of `bash`

Comment: Ok wildcards is not the answer I seek. need to think about zsh

Comment: You need to access one directory like that or there's multiple ?

Comment: Add your solution (which might be interesting by the way) as an answer instead of adding it to your question. That's what answers are made for!

Comment: Make that program just print the path and do a `cd $(icd XXXX)` --- you just rewrote that `find` part. Now your next task is... check what's more efficient, your program or `find` :-P.

Comment: I converted your solution to an answer.

Comment: Related to http://askubuntu.com/q/226417/41499. Also I'm surprised that nobody pointed you to **autojump**. With autojump you can simply type `j d` and it will take you to the `a b c d` directory. Check my answer to the linked question for more details: http://askubuntu.com/a/226431/41499

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution made by OP

No built-in command found here . But finally I am able to write a C program to use cd(lets call my program icd == (inode cd) ) to enter in a folder using inode value. Here I am posting the raw code.

But there is a fundamental problem I have faced here. While coding execution a C code from a bash needed to create child process under the bash process(parent process). From the child process the directory space is new, and I can not access parent process's directory space from there. So nothing could be done except invoked a new bash window from here. In future I will try to implement a new tab feature if people are interested in this. But I believe I have faced a lot of criticism for doing this. So people might not be interested. I have just done for my amusement.

RAW code is shared here,

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include<pwd.h>

using namespace std ;

int main(int argc , char *argv[] ) {

  struct stat ITR ;

  if( argc != 2 ) {
    printf("\nWrong Command\n\n") ;
    return 1 ;
  }

  long long given_inode = 0 ;
  for( int i =0 ; argv[1][i] ; i++ ){
    given_inode *= 10 ;
    given_inode += (argv[1][i]-'0') ;
  }

//  if (stat(argv[1], &ITR) == -1) {
//    perror("stat");
//    return 1  ;
//  }

  printf("%s\n",argv[0]) ;
    char PWD[1000] ; 
    getcwd( PWD , 1000 ) ;

  DIR *d;
  struct dirent *p;
  char path[100000] ;
  d = opendir(".");
  if( d != NULL ) {
    while( (p = readdir(d))!= NULL ) {
        strcpy( path , "./" ) ;
        strcat( path, p->d_name ) ;
        stat(path, &ITR) ;
        //printf("%s --> ",path) ;
        //printf("%ld\n",ITR.st_ino) ;
        if( ITR.st_ino == given_inode ) {
          strcpy( path , "gnome-terminal --working-directory=" ) ;
          strcat( path, PWD ) ;
                    strcat( path, "/" ) ;
                    strcat( path, p->d_name ) ;
                    system(path) ; 
                    //printf("%s\n",path) ;
                    return 0 ;
        }
    }
  }
  printf("icd %lld:No such file or directory\n",given_inode) ;
  return 0 ;

}
```

I am using gnome terminal here. Obviously For other distro the code will be changed.

Comment: If you could move to a directory within a shell script, you can source the script to accomplish what you want. The define an alias to shorten the command.

Answer (score 18):

Any entity in (most) file systems on Linux has an unique identifier called an `inode`. Notice that a file can have more than one name ([hardlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)), but directories have just one link in all the filesystems I know of. Notice that the concept of inode is *local* to the filesystem, so that in two different devices (partition or whatever) the uniqueness is not guaranteed.

You can see the inode of your directory with `ls -ldi`:

```
[:~] % ls -ldi tmp/uffa                     
20873234 drwxrwxr-x 2 romano romano 4096 Jun 26  2014 tmp/uffa
```

So you know that your directory has inode 20873234. Now you can switch to it with the command:

```
[:~] % cd "$(find ~ -inum 20873234 2> /dev/null)"  
[:~/tmp/uffa] %
```

(Note that the `2> /dev/null` is to shut up error messages about unreadable directories along the path.)

This command will scan the entirety of your home directory, so be patient.<sup>1</sup>

But what about using `cd` and the TAB-completion of your shell?

---

<sup>**1.**</sup> This must be the most<sup>2</sup> inefficient thing I ever posted ... an ode to entropy. The reason is that the “primary key” under which the access to a file or directory is optimized, fast and direct is — guess what? — the pathname: `/dir/dir/file_or_dir`. Moreover, to grant you access to a given directory, the system needs to check all the permissions in the path... so again, accessing by inode means scanning recursively the filesystem.

<sup>**2.**</sup> Well, you can make thing worse by scanning from `/`.<sup>3</sup>

<sup>**3.**</sup> But then it won't work, because inodes are unique only on a per-filesystem (per-mount) basis.

Comment: Thanks @Romano . Actually I was thinking about the problem. I do not know that the problem would turn into such inefficient solution. But think about the solution. You can easily  write a c program and put it into /bin and then try to execute it with the only inode number. I will post the code if I am able to write such think.

Comment: and also one think I need to know. I understand the first part of this command. "$(find ~ -inum 20873234 ******)" . but I do not know Why u are writting this,   "2> /dev/null". Can u please clarify once again.

Comment: @Maruf, it will not work, efficiency-wise. The "primary key" under which the access to a file or directory is optimized, fast and direct is, guess what, the pathname... `/dir/dir/file_or_dir`. Your C program will need to scan the filesystem too, and `find` has been optimized during the last 40 years... still --- why? If you need a shortcut, use `a="/my/really/strange and long/dir path name/"` and then `cd "$a"`. Can't beat it. Or use symlinks.

Comment: Actually buddy life is like a problem solving. Once you think , until seeing the last u won't stop. If find is inefficient then I will code it with plain C. Keep in touch. I have a exam tomorrow. May be I can picture the solution now. I will try to post the solution Tomorrow after my exam. keep in touch.

Comment: And thanks for the term inode. Actually it solves the problem. I was not aware of inode.

Comment: `find` is coded in C. You can find find's sources (eh!) around. But hey, you can enjoy trying it ---- have fun!

Comment: A good one +1. I was at the edge of writing something similar, but I was too lazy, since the task has no sense at all. @Rmano

Comment: So u are doing the task always ," what makes sense ... !!!!!!!" :v @Pilot6

Comment: Hey @Rmano Finally I have coded it in C. Don't forget to comment.

Comment: @Rmano I would add that in general, even on a single filesystem, there may be several files that have the same inode, i.e., hardlinks. Since we are speaking about directories here, it happens to be true that each directory has a unique inode (directories cannot be hardlinked.) Also, I think the reason that one cannot directly access a file via its inode is that this would bypass any directory traversal, needed to determine whether a user is allowed to access the corresponding resource. (So if a directory could be accessed by its inode, then the kernel would have to determine its path anyway.)

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa --- you're (clearly) right in your comment.

Answer (score 8):

You can make <kbd>Tab</kbd> rotate the available folders instead of listing them.
Edit the file `~/.inputrc` and add

```
"\C-i": menu-complete
"\e[Z": "\e-1\C-i"
```

If you want it for all users, edit `/etc/inputrc` instead.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> to make it effective.

Now use `cd`<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate to your folder without writing its name. `cd`<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will rotate in the other direction.

Worth remembering that `cd -` will take you to the last visited folder.

Comment: This is a good answer. Can you make it display once and then rotate?

Comment: You can assign this to another shortcut. I use Eclipse and I'm used to Ctrl + space for auto complete so I use  "\C- ": menu-complete instead, leaving tab as it is.

Answer (score 5):

You can use shell wildcards.

For instance, I can do

```
cd a?b?c?d
```

or

```
cd a\*b\*c\*d
```

And it will expand the wildcards to the actual name and change to that directory. Assuming that's the only directory which matches.

If you have both `a b c d` and `a1b2c3d`, then `cd a?b?c?d` will expand to either `cd a1b2c3d a b c d` or `cd a b c d a1b2c3d` (the actual order will depend on the kernel, filesystem...), and bash will silently move you to the first path.

On the other hand, you often not have so similarly named folders, so something like `a*d` is enough to expand that without having to type all the intermediate characters. This is specially useful when you are not actually able to type it (eg. the names are in a different script, or even a different encoding), and you would otherwise have needed to octal-encode the filename.

Answer (score 3):

You can find this directory in a file manager, e.g. nautilus and just drag and drop it to terminal.

If you previously type `cd` in terminal, you will get the command.

Comment: Actually I am trying to do everything from terminal.  :).  So no need to think about nautilus. I think there must be a procedure to access the file. As Linux always save a unique identifier for a particular file. But I don't know How to do that or can this be actually done.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. It is not possible to change to a directory not entering its name some way.

Comment: See the statement. I have updated it.

Comment: Or if this is the problem with a single file, you could add a alias.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's exactly what your asking for, but `zsh` has some neat tricks to access a directory by other means than typing the directory's strict name; for one, you can type a part of the name and it will expand to the directory's full name, which allows for very useful things, for example:

[image]

Hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to double click on the directory name (assuming it is visible on the screen), then type cd followed by space and click the wheel button on your mouse and it will copy and paste the directory name that you have highlighted. Pressing the enter key will then change to the directory required.

I use this procedure all the time and it's not just confined to directory names. It can be used for any commands using the command line.

Good luck.

Comment: This will not escape special characters

Answer (score 1):

If it is just one or a few directories, why not have aliases in your bashrc or whatever init files? For example:

```
alias abc='cd /tmp/"a b c"'
```

Then whenever you want to go in there, just type `abc`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a program to create a hash table for all of your OS directories. It would basically be a tree flattening program.

But then you could do something like `hash-cd 32okjv02` and it would do the hash table lookup for the `32okjv02` to directory mapping. and jump to your directory. And it would be really fast once you got all your directories indexed.

You would have to alias mkdir to call this program every new directory and maybe write a hash-table check/refresh command you could cron every minute and on logon.