# Go back to default directory in terminal

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, cd

I'm using Kubuntu 22.04, with "Konsole" and "Terminator".

I have set a default starting directory for each of them (let's call it `/my/quite/complex/default/destination/directory`).

After working a lot, traveling between many different directories, I want to go back to that default, without having to type all that... Is there a simple `cd` command to do it?

Note: that directory ***IS NOT*** `/home/myUser`, therefore `cd ~` won't solve the problem, and `cd -` only goes back to the last one, not the very first.

Thank you all.

Comment: If you are using the bash shell, you may find `pushd` and `popd` useful - refer to the bash manual under [The Directory Stack](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Directory-Stack). See also [Short-cut for switching to a given directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226417/short-cut-for-switching-to-a-given-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `~/.bashrc` to *store* the starting directory somewhere, usually in a shell variable, whenever the shell is launched. For example:

```
startdir=$PWD
```

Once you have that, you can either use it directly as `cd "$startdir"` (for this you could choose a shorter variable name such as `$h`), or make aliases / functions:

```
alias ret='cd "$startdir"'
```

```
ret() { cd "$startdir"; }
```

Comment: Simple, direct, succinct, and just works.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- An alias, added to your `~/.bashrc`, can already cut it:

  ```
    alias mcd='cd /my/quite/complex/default/destination/directory'
  ```

  Now, the command `mcd`will bring you to that directory.
- In `~/.bashrc`, you may define your directory in a variable as

  ```
  export MD=/my/quite/complex/default/destination/directory
  ```

  Then, `cd $MD` will take you to that directory.
- In a slightly more sophisticated approach, you can override your `cd` command using a function that, without arguments, brings you to your desired directory, and with arguments works as usual. This can be done with a bash function as follows. Include it in `~/.bashrc`.

  ```
  cd () {
     if [ -z $1 ] ;  then
        command cd /my/quite/complex/default/destination/directory 
     else
        command cd $@
     fi
  }
  ```
- Changing the `$HOME` variable in `~./bashrc` will fundamentally achieve what you want. This would not affect the desktop environment, because the changed variable is only in effect in your interactive terminals and subshells, but there is still a chance that specific graphical (system) tools may malfunction with the wrong `HOME` set.

  Temporarily changing HOME in the function, however, should be safe:

  ```
  cd () {
     OLDHOME=$HOME
     HOME=/my/quite/complex/default/destination/directory
     command cd $@
     HOME=$OLDHOME ; unset OLDHOME
  }
  ```

Comment: Great explanation. But I'll stick with `user1686`'s answer, for simplicity and using the `$PWD` variable (more flexible: if I change the default terminal starting directory, it will just follow naturally).

Answer (score 0):

Look at CDPATH from the bash man pages.
`export CDPATH=".:~:/my/quite/complex/default/destination"`

Then cd directory  will take you to /my/quite/complex/default/destination/directory.  Provided you don't have "directory" any earlier in the CDPATH.